# How to prove $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{x\cos(bx)}{x^2+a^2} \mathrm{d}x$ (for any$ \, a>0, \, b>0)$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

How to prove
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{x\cos(bx)}{x^2+a^2} \mathrm{d}x$$ (for any $a,b>0$)
is convergent? Any help please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The integral is $0$ for any $a > 0$, $b$ because the function is odd. Zero is as good a convergent value as any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\displaystyle \int_{-M}^{M} \frac {x \cos (bx)} {x^{2}+a^{2}}\mathrm{d}x=\left. \frac {\sin (bx)} b \frac  x{x^{2}+a^{2} }\right|_{-M}^{M} -\int_{-M}^{M} \frac {\sin (bx)} b \frac {x^{2}+a^{2}-2ax}  {(x^{2}+a^{2})^{2}} \mathrm{d}x $.

In the last integral use the fact that $|\sin (bx)| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The function is odd, so it converges to $0$ if the integral exists (this is not the case for $\frac1x$ for instance). Since $a$ and $b$ are strictly positive, you can assume WLOG they are both $1$ (just change variables accordingly). Then you notice the term $\displaystyle \int_0 ^{\infty} \frac{x\cos x}{x^2 +1} \mathrm{ d}x$ doesn't "give problems" at $0$ and $\infty$, meaning it converges to something (and thus your integral equals $0$). In $0$ it is obviously convergent, can you see why this is the case also for infinity?